# grep multiple words in a file with help of fixed string switch

Tags: unix, grep

I have multiple strings in a file which have special character `$`, when I search strings by ignoring `$` with `\` using single quotes it returns empty results.

My search strings are `set char_1($lock)` and `set new_char_clear_3($unlock)`.

I tried searching with

```
fgrep 'set char_1($lock)\|set new_char_clear_3($unlock)' filename.txt
```

but it returns empty results. However the following command gives results for 1st string

```
fgrep 'set char_1($lock)' filename.txt
```

Tried with `grep -F` as well which return same results as above.

How do i get both results with single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the alternation, i.e. the `|` to mean *"either of the 2 strings"*, you need to use `grep -E`, and if you use that, you must escape its understanding of the dollar and the parentheses, so you want:

```
grep -E 'set char_1\(\$lock)|set new_char_clear_3\(\$unlock)' YOUR_FILE
```

Comment: I did try with -e but couldn't get results. The command you gave worked with additional  backslash  before the closing braces.                                                                                                                        `grep -E 'set char_1\(\$lock\)|set new_char_clear_3\(\$unlock\)' YOUR_FILE`